# recurcive CTE how to use it

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query

I want to create a recursive cte by passing a date through it until it reaches final date. Can anyone show me an example of how to do it

I need to pass a starting date and a final date and make a count of how many students there were in every year!

where :date and :finaldate is an input

```
 with seventeen as 
(
    select  count(studentid)
    from students s
    join periodrange p on p.idx = s.periodrangeidx
    where p.validdate between :date and :finaldate
)
```

I want to have the sum of the students for each year

Would something like this even work or did i dream to far for recrusive CTE

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  I don't think a recursive CTE is the best way to solve this problem in Postgres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need CTE, you can just use a group by and count:

```
select  count(studentid), extrac(year from p.validatdate) as Year
from students s
join periodrange p on p.idx = s.periodrangeidx
where p.validdate between :date and :finaldate
Group by extrac(year from p.validatdate), studentid
```

Comment: giving it a try